# Serilog json config: How to refer to another value from the same appsettings.json file?

Tags: serilog

I'm switching from NLog to Serilog, and trying to do as much config as possible in appsettings.json instead of code. I need to specify a value in there by pointing to another config item in appsettings. To illustrate, here's a much simplified example how we do it using NLog. The "serviceUri" property ends up with the value `https://qwerty.blob.core.windows.net/`. With NLog, this is using NLog's config setting layout renderer. I'd like to do the same with Serilog, but have not been able to find any documentation on this. Does Serilog have an equivalent capability? Any tips appreciated!

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AppConfig": {
    "LogBlobStorageUri": "https://qwerty.blob.core.windows.net/"
  },
  "NLog": { 
    "targets": {
      "async": true,
      "blobStorageDefaultLogger": {
        "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
        "layout": "${longdate:universalTime=true}|${message}",
        "serviceUri": "${configsetting:item=AppConfig.LogBlobStorageUri}"  <-- how to do this with Serilog?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: would be helpful if you also add your serilog configuration what you trying.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible in serilog.
in below example I had defined connectionstring in one section and used as a reference in the serilog section.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=Test;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  }
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo","Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
       ...
      }
    },
  "Enrich": ...,
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "MSSqlServer",
      "Args": {
        "connectionString": "DefaultConnection", <== here i have used setting name from file itself.
        "sinkOptionsSection": {
          ...     
        },
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
        ....
      }
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

It works for connectionstring but I have not tried for other settings.

give it a try. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not sure what magic is happening there in your case with being able to read and reference the "DefaultConnection" property, but that same magic does not appear to be in play in my case. I specified  LogBlobStorageUri  like this (below), but it just then complains about an invalid container name.
`"serviceUri": "LogBlobStorageUri"`

Comment: As I mentioned, I have only tried for connectionstring.

Comment: which sink are you using ? this is specific to sink. for example MSSQLserver sink has special handling for reading connectionstring from outside serilog configuration section.